# How to write this code efficently

Tags: apex

As the current code has the SOQL within for loop ,it isn't good.
Please suggest how to make it more efficient.

```
Set<id> ids = (new Map<Id,Account>([select id from Account where id in: accids]).keyset());

      map<id,integer> ak =   new Map<id,Contact>([select count() from Contact where AccountId in: accids]);

      system.debug(ak); // This linee is also giving a Datatype mismatch error.How shall i resolve this?

      List<Account> ContactCountOnAccount = new List<Account>();
    for(integer i =0;i < AccIds.size();i++)
    {
        Account acc = new Account();

        acc.id = AccIds[i];
        acc.Number_of_Contacts__c = [select count() from Contact where AccountId =: AccIds[i] ];

        ContactCountOnAccount.add(acc);
    }

      if(ContactCountOnAccount.size() >0)
      {
            update ContactCountOnAccount;
      }
```

Comment: Are you trying to mimic a rollup summary field? If so, you should just install and implement the **[Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)** tool.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand from code, you want to calculate number of Contacts related to set ids of Accounts.

```
List<Account> acctsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
for(AggregateResult result :[
   select count(Id), AccountId
   from Contact
   where AccountId in :accids
   group by AccountId
]){
    acctsToUpdate.add(
        new Account(
            Id = (Id) result.get('AccountId'),
            Number_of_Contacts__c = (String) String.valueOf(result.get('expr0'))
            )
        );
}
update acctsToUpdate;
```

This code uses [SOQL for loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm) (queries including an aggregate function don't support queryMore, but anyway), and soql is moved out from loop.

condition `if(ContactCountOnAccount.size() >0)` is not necessary, as empty list has nothing to update

`Set<id> ids = (new Map<Id,Account>([select id from Account where id in: accids]).keyset());`
this line has no sense. You already have ids of Accounts, no need to query them one more time

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Account> ContactCountOnAccount = new List<Account>();
for(Account acc : [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accids]) {

    acc.Number_of_Contacts__c = acc.contacts.size();
    ContactCountOnAccount.add(acc);
} 
if(!ContactCountOnAccount.isEmpty()) {
    update ContactCountOnAccount;
}
```

soql is placed inside for loop because hitting the governor limits.